Why is my UV map not circular?
The UV map is not circular as it should be but in the shape of my earcup model. The next problem is the star shapes are distorted even though in the original picture, it is not like that.




I'm not sure to understand, giving the way you've unwapped your object, the image is projected the way it supposed to be, could you please elaborate?

I was following a YouTube video and in the video, the UV map is just a flat circle when unwrap but in my case it looks 3D.

You just need to unwrap again, select the face and press U > Unwrap, for the ring you'll need to orthogonize the unwrap

First thing remove the overlapping vertices with a M > Merge by Distance. A solution could be to select the headphone, press Shift7 for front view of the selection, unwrap with the Project from View mode:

Then activate the Sync button of the UV Editor, select the bottom edge loop of the headphone and scale it up in the UV Editor to avoid the stretched image on the side of the headphone:


Ok so the circle UV and the stars on the front flat surface are fixed but for the part where I have to scale bottom edge loop in the UV of the headphone, it is not working and the stars are still distorted on those corners
